# Is this site limited only to Web applications?

Tags: discussion

We can see User Experience in our daily routine of life in many products. but I am seeing the questions here are only related to Web applications. Is this site limited only to Web applications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web applications is predominantly the focus, but that is only because the majority of the site users work with such applications on a daily basis. There are more web developers than board-game developers on this site, for instance.

However, take a look at the questions tagged as [physical](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical) to see some questions on non-web UX.

A bit of variety on this site is always good, so provided questions are still suitable from a Q&A perspective then they're likely welcome here.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers will be equally relevant to web and desktop applications, unless specified otherwise. Mobile apps are also a very common subject. So no, it's definitely not just web applications.

Answer (score 0):

There are many people that monitor the physical-oriented tags.  Because they are not the volume of digital UX tags, the people the do answer are often quite eager to connect on non-digital topics.

You should feel welcome to engage with this part of the community.